# Linkage error between C++ executable and tensorflow.lib

Tags: c++, tensorflow, linkage

I have been compiling tensorflow 2.4 following this [link](https://medium.com/vitrox-publication/deep-learning-frameworks-tensorflow-build-from-source-on-windows-python-c-cpu-gpu-d3aa4d0772d8).

Out of the build process I have:

- tensorflow.lib
- tensorflow.dll
- tensorflow headers

To build my application I am using cmake, and the following line handle the linkage:

```
target_link_libraries(${ADD_EXAMPLE_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/tensorflow/tensorflow.lib)
```

When building I get the following error:

```
[ 95%] Linking CXX executable tensorflow_main.exe
CMakeFiles\tensorflow_main.dir/objects.a(tensorflow_main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/tmac3/Desktop/PhD/Homing-Pigeon/examples/tensorflow_main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `tf_git_version()'
...
```

CMake (more precisely ld) does not find the tensorflow symbols... Therefore, I used DUMPBIN to check whether the symbols are present in tensorflow.lib:

```
?>DUMPBIN /EXPORTS tensorflow.lib > exports.txt
?>findstr "tf_git_version" exports.txt
        ?tf_git_version@@YAPEBDXZ (char const * __cdecl tf_git_version(void))
```

**Problem:** The symbol seems to be present in tensorflow.lib and I ask CMake to link my executable to this file.

**Question:** What am I missing?

**Edit 1:**

```
?>DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS tensorflow.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.28.29337.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file tensorflow.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 01017299 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | __IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_tensorflow
002 C0000040 SECT2  notype       Section      | .idata$2
003 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .idata$6
004 C0000040 UNDEF  notype       Section      | .idata$4
005 C0000040 UNDEF  notype       Section      | .idata$5
006 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
007 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | ⌂tensorflow_NULL_THUNK_DATA

String Table Size = 0x58 bytes

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 01017299 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR

String Table Size = 0x1D bytes

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 01017299 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | ⌂tensorflow_NULL_THUNK_DATA

String Table Size = 0x20 bytes

  Summary

          CC .debug$S
          14 .idata$2
          14 .idata$3
           8 .idata$4
           8 .idata$5
          10 .idata$6
```

Comment: Is the symbol reference in the lib file defined or undefined?

Comment: I am not sure, what defined/undefined symbol reference are? Do you have a way to check? Or a good resource about defined/undefined symbol reference?

Comment: Try running `DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS` on the lib file, what does the column for that symbol return?

Comment: I have edied my question to include the command output. Am I rigth to think that the symbol is not expose and therefore can not be found by CMake?

Comment: If so, what is the difference between /EXPORTS and /SYMBOLS?

Comment: [`/SYMBOLS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/symbols?view=msvc-160) give you the symbol table, looking to see if it was defined (3rd col).